# where is jar physically located?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My day 1 of learning Azure devops.

I made 1 very simple Spring boot app and going step by step.

I managed to build a pipeline in which I am getting all the code from Azure Repo .. then running build and creating jar.

I see below on *PublishBuildArtifacts* task .. but where is this jar physically located ?
How can I access that ?

```
Starting: PublishBuildArtifacts
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish build artifacts
Description  : Publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines or a Windows file share
Version      : 1.158.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts
==============================================================================
Async Command Start: Upload Artifact
Uploading 107 files
Uploading 'drop1/target/azure-devops-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' (25%)
Uploading 'drop1/target/azure-devops-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' (50%)
Uploading 'drop1/target/azure-devops-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' (75%)
Uploading 'drop1/target/azure-devops-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' (100%)
File upload succeed.
Upload '/home/vsts/work/1/a' to file container: '#/7550295/drop1'
Associated artifact 1 with build 11
Async Command End: Upload Artifact
Finishing: PublishBuildArtifacts
```

Comment: It's located in Azure DevOps. How you access it depends on what you want to do with it. Generally, you consume that artifact in a deployment pipeline to deploy it somewhere.

Comment: thanks ... lets say I want to download it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After publishing the artifact, we could see the artifact in the build summary page and download it via the button **Download artifacts** you could check the pic below.

[image]